# Responsive Video With Background/Border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use the following image with the video inside the tv screen and be responsive. I've tried for the last few hours but maybe I am over my head or asking too much of CSS.

Is there a way to do this that I don't know about, I need the video to be positioned in the tv screen as the browser is resized to stay with that position.

Attempted to adjust the top and left positions but having no luck. This is where I left off, I don't know what properties I need to look at or play with.

CSS

```
#iss-television {
    background: url('/images/ig-television_prop.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
    background-size: contain;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

    #iss-television video {
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        top: 20%;
        left: 10%;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="iss-television">
        <video poster="/video/iss-video_cover.jpg" controls="">
            <source src="/video/video_iss.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

IMAGE
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/te921kws/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 text-center">
        <video poster="/video/iss-video_cover.jpg" controls="" class="embed-responsive-item img img-responsive">
            <source src="/video/video_iss.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, do remember to remove the #iss-television properties from your css

Comment: How does this center it inside the tv image? that was the question.

Comment: Can you kindly add a jsfiddle of your complete html and css please :) You just need to add a slight negative margin to the left to keep it inside the tv screen :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/te921kws/3/ >> The video doesn't fit inside the tv. If I use your snippet it's a bit better but still doesn't size correctly with mobile devices.